# Pass in an entire directory into the 'require()' function using Webpack Encore

Tags: symfony, webpack, webpack-encore

Webpack Encore is new to me and I'm struggling with static files. In order to use static files, you have to require them in your `main.js` like so:

```
require('images/myImage.jpg');
```

This file would then be added to the `manifest.json` and you can refer to it using `{{ asset(myImage.jpg) }}`. How do I pass an entire directory into the `required()` function? I don't want to add all my static images one by one.

I have already tried the 'require-dir' [library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/require-dir), to no avail. It kept outputting this error: `require.extensions is not supported by webpack`.

Is there an easier way to achieve what I want?

Comment: I'm looking for do that me too !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `require.context` for this. Lets say you want to include all img's in the favicon directory, you would do the following.

```
// Load all favicons in directory
require.context('../img/favicon', false, /\.png$|.ico$/);
```

No need to store the result in a object or use it in your code. Webpack will just include the all the files matching `.png and .ico` in your configured output directory.

This way also gives you controll over the files required with the regex at the end.